# HTML encoding: eastern european languages

Tags: html, character-encoding

My program is fetching messages from a database, which contains English, German and several Eastern European languages. My Python script sets the encoding via:

```
<meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

and use the values fetched correctly from the database (if I check within my logs).

Unfortunately all browsers I tested (IE8, Firefox 3.0.10, Opera 9.64) switch based on my local language settings to:

- Western ISO-8859-1 in Firefox
- Western European (Windows) in IE
- Automatic in Opera

Everything works fine as soon as I switch the character encoding manually in the browser.

The same happens if I manually generate the HTML file using UTF-8 (tested with TextMate respective jEdit), although both editors display the content correctly.

That works fine for English and German, but i.e. not for Russian. How can I force the "correct" character encoding?

**ANSWER**

The following entry within the VirtualHost (Apache configuration) section did the trick for me:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Many thanks for pointing me into the right direction, that helped a lot!

Comment: Very nice question. Much interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the document is transfered over HTTP, [the HTTP header information are the crutial information](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.2.2):

> […] conforming user agents must observe the following priorities when determining a document's character encoding (from highest priority to lowest):
>
> 1. An HTTP "`charset`" parameter in a "`Content-Type`" field.
> 2. A `META` declaration with "`http-equiv`" set to "`Content-Type`" and a value set for "`charset`".
> 3. The `charset` attribute set on an element that designates an external resource.

So make sure you declare the character encoding in the [`Content-Type` header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) and not just inside the document.